# Packer: Sample file for Openstack

Tags: openstack, packer, openstack-nova

Can someone please provide me with a sample file for Packer creating OS image? I have this one:

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "openstack",
    "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
    "tenant_name": "mytenant",
    "flavor": "m1.tiny",
    "identity_endpoint": "http://1.2.3.4:5000/",
    "availability_zone": "az1",
    "source_image": "Ubuntu 16.04 With Proxy",
    "image_name": "Ubuntu 16.04 With Proxy and Python"
  }],

  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "script": "python.sh"
    }
  ]

}
```

but OS always returns:

```
==> openstack: Error launching source server: Invalid request due to incorrect syntax or missing required parameters.
```

I have no idea what I am missing.

Of course i have correct `OS_` env values preset for my Nova API.

Comment: Link to a full debug log by running `PACKER_LOG=1 packer build template.json`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xJvkLmyp

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `source_image_name` or use the ID to reference the image

From the docs:

> - `source_image` (string) - The ID or full URL to the base image to use. This is the image that will be used to launch a new server and provision it. Unless you specify completely custom SSH settings, the source image must have cloud-init installed so that the keypair gets assigned properly.
> - `source_image_name` (string) - The name of the base image to use. This is an alternative way of providing `source_image` and only either of them can be specified.

See [source_image](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/openstack.html#source_image)

Comment: Thanks, but I am still not there: I had to ad "networks" parameter with the UUID of my network and now I am here again - http://pastebin.com/9ht1MkYT

Comment: Dump http request/responses to the nova api with tcpdump, wirkeshark or httpry. Or if you can check in OpenStack the request/response that failes. pastbin that but be sure to remove any credentials. I guess that your nova api doesn't work as expected.

Comment: For me, in addition to the networks, I needed to add the ID of the floating IP address I was using too. You can get that using `openstack floating ip list` cmd.